Format string template defined outside of loop?
I'm getting odd results when defining a format string outside of a loop.  I want to define a variable containing my format string like:
MYSTRING = f"filepath/{year}/{month}"

If I define it outside the loop I get repeated same value.  If I copy/paste that string inside the loop it works fine.
This one goes all the way back to 2023 as expected:
last_n_months = 12
months = date.today().year * 12 + date.today().month - 1 # Months since year 0 minus 1
tuples = [((months - i) // 12, (months - i) % 12 + 1) for i in range(last_n_months)]

for item in tuples:
    year = str(item[0])
    month = str(item[1])
    # string used in directly with the format() function
    print(f"xyz/Year={year}/Month={month}".format())

------------------------
xyz/Year=2024/Month=11
xyz/Year=2024/Month=10
xyz/Year=2024/Month=9
xyz/Year=2024/Month=8
xyz/Year=2024/Month=7
xyz/Year=2024/Month=6
xyz/Year=2024/Month=5
xyz/Year=2024/Month=4
xyz/Year=2024/Month=3
xyz/Year=2024/Month=2
xyz/Year=2024/Month=1
xyz/Year=2023/Month=12

But this one repeats the same year/month for each:
# the format string
myformatstring = f"xyz/Year={year}/Month={month}"

last_n_months = 12
months = date.today().year * 12 + date.today().month - 1 # Months since year 0 minus 1
tuples = [((months - i) // 12, (months - i) % 12 + 1) for i in range(last_n_months)]

for item in tuples:
    year = str(item[0])
    month = str(item[1])
    # use the format string variable from outside the loop
    print(myformatstring.format())

------------------------
xyz/Year=2023/Month=12
xyz/Year=2023/Month=12
xyz/Year=2023/Month=12
xyz/Year=2023/Month=12
xyz/Year=2023/Month=12
xyz/Year=2023/Month=12
xyz/Year=2023/Month=12
xyz/Year=2023/Month=12
xyz/Year=2023/Month=12
xyz/Year=2023/Month=12
xyz/Year=2023/Month=12
xyz/Year=2023/Month=12

Any ideas?

Your f-string is evaluated immediately with the current values of year and month. The resulting string (in your second snippet) doesn't have the placeholders you expect it to have.
Note that in your first snippet the call of the .format() method has no effect, as the f-notation already does that job.
Don't use an f-string notation, but a plain string literal with braces. Then pass the variables to the format method and it will work:
from datetime import date

# the format string
myformatstring = "xyz/Year={}/Month={}"   # don't evaluate the placeholders here

last_n_months = 12
months = date.today().year * 12 + date.today().month - 1
tuples = [((months - i) // 12, (months - i) % 12 + 1) 
          for i in range(last_n_months)]

for year, month in tuples:
    print(myformatstring.format(year, month))  # ...pass the values to inject


You're confusing f-strings with str.format
You can achieve your objective in a number of ways. Here are 2 ideas:
from datetime import date

last_n_months = 12
months = date.today().year * 12 + date.today().month - 1 # Months since year 0 minus 1
tuples = [((months - i) // 12, (months - i) % 12 + 1) for i in range(last_n_months)]

# use f-strings
for year, month in tuples:
    print(f"xyz/Year={year}/Month={month}")

# or
print()

# use str.format
for year, month in tuples:
    print("xyz/Year={}/Month={}".format(year, month))

Output:
xyz/Year=2024/Month=11
xyz/Year=2024/Month=10
xyz/Year=2024/Month=9
xyz/Year=2024/Month=8
xyz/Year=2024/Month=7
xyz/Year=2024/Month=6
xyz/Year=2024/Month=5
xyz/Year=2024/Month=4
xyz/Year=2024/Month=3
xyz/Year=2024/Month=2
xyz/Year=2024/Month=1
xyz/Year=2023/Month=12

xyz/Year=2024/Month=11
xyz/Year=2024/Month=10
xyz/Year=2024/Month=9
xyz/Year=2024/Month=8
xyz/Year=2024/Month=7
xyz/Year=2024/Month=6
xyz/Year=2024/Month=5
xyz/Year=2024/Month=4
xyz/Year=2024/Month=3
xyz/Year=2024/Month=2
xyz/Year=2024/Month=1
xyz/Year=2023/Month=12

